# How to hide "add to cart" button but show configurable options - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart

I need to hide the add to cart button so currently, I have a plugin aroundIsSalable which sets the return to false if you are logged out.

The issue with this is that it also hides the options for a configurable product. How can I get it set saleable to false but also show the configurable options

Comment: If you managed to solve this, can you share the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Plugin. Override addtocart.phtm template and hide/show button using custom module helper in addtocart.phtml.

catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">NAMESAPCE_MODUEL::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
</referenceBlock>
```